# Maintaining a reference to a record ID after a merge

Tags: merge

So the scenario is as follows. I have a record (A) in the system. An external process inserts a new record(B), and then has the record ID for (B). It is then realised that (A) and (B) need to be merged. The process is that (B) is merged into (A).

However, the external system has the ID for (B).

Is there anyway to use the id of (B) to reference (A) into which it has been merged?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, create a [Lookup field](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=custom_field_types.htm&language=en_US) that is lookup to the same object, e.g. "Merged To" and populate that when merge process is complete. I imagine you would want to update this field on B's record to point to A. So when your reviewing B's record in the UI or Reports you can see and drill into which record it was merged into. Either way a Lookup field to the same object should give you the audit information i think your looking to implement.

Comment: This would seem to offer a solution, however how do you envisage the "Merged to" field being updated? Surely this will require a manual process for the user? Or is there something I am missing here?

Comment: I was assuming the merge process was a peace of code of some kind and that that peace of code would after doing the merge update this field? If my assumption was wrong, can you elaborate more on the technical aspects of the process above?

Comment: The merge is currently manual using the standard Salesforce merge process. I'm not aware of a way to override it....yet.

Answer (score 0):

I totally agree with the @Andrew provided, and that will work.  I guess I would think thought that although it's more work up front, wouldn't you rather push the change back out to the external system so that it is synced with your SF org.  There very well might be scenarios where you might want to allow duplicates in your external system, but was just wondering if this is the case here.

In many of my orgs we have bi-directional pushes periodically that push the changes and deduplication back to our back office legacy systems.

This may not be something that is desired in your certain scenario, but thought I would bring it up just in case.

Comment: We won't be pushing out records to the external system. Rather it will, when it needs them, request them via the API. Out bound messaging would be the best option in that instance I think.